# How to prove convergence in distribution of the sum of two independent random variables without using characteristic functions?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ are i.i.d distributed with finite mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$, $Y_1, Y_2, ... Y_m$ are i.i.d distributed with finite mean $\theta$ and finite variance $\tau^2$. Let $\bar{X_n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$, $\bar{Y_m} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m} Y_j$. For any $i \in n, j\in m$, $X_i \perp Y_j$.

Then with CLT, $\bar{X}_n \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$ and $\bar{Y}_m \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(\theta, \frac{\tau^2}{m})$.  How to show that $\bar{X}_n + \bar{Y}_m \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(\mu + \theta, \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \frac{\tau^2}{m})$ without using characteristic functions?

Comment: Your want to prove it by definition of convergence in distribution? Here is a question : how do you find the continuity points of $X+Y$? You need to show pointwise convergence at these points, so how do you locate them?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Sorry, I forgot to mention that all the functions are continuous. I've updated the condition up there.

Comment: Ok. Now what is the distribution of $X_n+Y_n$? Start from there.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I added more detail. Sorry about the vague question.

Comment: Thanks, we could have had an XY situation. +1. I will think and get back, the question has changed a fair bit.

Comment: You mean $\overline{X}_n+\overline{Y}_n$ at the very end, do you ?

Comment: @nicomezi Yes, sorry for the typo. I changed that.

Comment: Sorry but your question does not make sense, when you take the limit (in distribution) you have $n$ and/or $m$ going to $\infty$ right ? How is the limit depending on them ? Also there is still a $Y_n$ without an overline near the end.

Comment: @nicomezi Let's make another assumption that $m / (m + n) \rightarrow \lambda$ for some $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ when $m, n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Please take some time to review your question. even with this assumption the claim does not make sense.